# CSS hover effect with figure and figcaption overlayed

Tags: html, css, hover, overlay, figure

Looking for some styling CSS help. I want to create an image box (that should be link) with centered text that is diplaying over the image with color half-transparent overlay background. We have such given HTML:

```
<div class="figure">
  <a href="#" class="link1">
    <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/css/klematis.jpg" alt="flower Klematis">
    <div class="figcaption">Klematis</div>
  </a>
</div>
```

The code is analogical of figure/figcaption HTML5 structure.
Here's the case:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dYaYqV

On hover overlay background should hide (which is the case), and opacity of image increase to full.

**Problem 1:**
Text is not centered with such position setting (absolute).

**Problem 2:** 
The overlay in this example is bigger (in the bottom of the image) due to some styling of , I think,  element. Overlay should be exact as the image.

**Problem 3:**
Text should hide as well as overlay during img mouse hover

No JS if possible, only CSS. Can you help? Thanks, J.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have edited your codepen example a bit, and i think this is exactly what you want
HTML:

```
 <div id="1" class="figure">
  <a href="#" class="link1">
    <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/css/klematis.jpg" alt="flower Klematis">
    <div class="figcaption"><h4>Klematis</h4></div>
  </a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.figure {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 10%;
    margin-right: 1%;
    left:20px;
}
.figure a{
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position:relative;
  z-index:2;
}
.figure a img{
  width:100%;
  display:block;
}
.figcaption {
    font-size: 0.8em;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    z-index: 2;
    height:100%;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.4);
    transition:background-color 0.4s ease;

}
.figcaption h4{
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  -moz-transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.figure a:hover .figcaption {
  background-color:transparent;
}
```

sorry, forget to hide text on hover, here is the edited codepen http://codepen.io/gopal280377/pen/QjYyLL

Comment: Sorry for late reponse. This seems exactly what I needed. Looks good. Thank you

Comment: Most Welcome @JanDesta

Answer (score 0):

tested on google chrome, hope it works for you

assign width to .figcaption to enable text-align,

moved anchor tag to parent of code block (my preference)

overlay overflow is probably due to undeclared image dimensions,

```
<a href="#" class="link1">
    <div id="1" class="figure">
        <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/css/klematis.jpg" alt="flower Klematis">
        <div class="figcaption">Klematis</div>
    </div>
 </a>


.figure {
   position: relative;
   width: 10%;
   height: auto;
   background:rgba(92,104,117,0.8);
   overflow: hidden;
   }
.figcaption {
   position: absolute;
   font-size: 0.8em;
   width: 100%;
   letter-spacing: 0.1em;
   text-align: center;
   top: 50px;
   z-index: 1 !important;
   }
.figure img {
   width: 100%;
   opacity: 0.5
   }
.link1:hover img {
   opacity: 1;
   -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
   transition: .3s ease-in-out;
   }
.link1:hover .figcaption {
   display: none;
   background:rgba(92,104,117,0.0);
   }
```

Comment: This creates <a> element for whole width of outer box element + annoyoing strip of background under the image. See: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MaRzyG . Anyway, thank you for your help. Best Regards!